# Navigation in Windows 10 vs code not going to virtualenv library when the same library is installed at user level

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I haven't found a question that specifically addresses this issue, if someone can find one that'll be much appreciated.

Running vs code using a virtualenv on Windows 10. I've configured my user settings as such:
`"python.pythonPath": "C:/virtualenv/NNvenv/Scripts/python.exe"`
And in the bottom left it shows that the Python executable is from this path.
However, I'm using F12 to navigate through my keras module, say for example with the following code:

```
from keras import Sequential
model = Sequential()
model.fit_generator()
```

And if I press F12 on fit_generator(), it doesn't go to the definition within `C:\virtualenv\NNvenv\Lib\site-packages\keras\models.py`, rather going to `C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\keras\models.py`.

Why is it not navigating to the virtualenv site packages, and how would I configure it to go to the correct library? This is pretty essential as I'm debugging keras code and want to edit the correct files when doing so.

I could change the PythonPath system environment variable, but then what's the point of even using the virtual environment. Is there some vs code configuration option I'm missing?

Comment: It a bag story, you can find it on vscode github page. Fix coming very soon (last news).

Comment: Thanks, could you link to the story?

Comment: Starts [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1033), perhaps important [comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/pull/1418#issuecomment-382175060)

Comment: Ah so it uses Jedi for navigation, makes sense.

Comment: @PCresswell if you want to see if the latest changes will fix your issue, please try a [development build](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#development-build) of the extension and let us know if this fixed your issue (and if it didn't then please file a bug).